# Project "MyProject" has higher compiler option than running Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jvm, java-6

I am trying to rebuild Hibernate configuration but i got `Wrong Compiler Settings` error, please find below screenshots of my App configuration and a of the error:

[image: Error Message]

[image: Build Path]

[image: Java Compiler]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was because Eclipse ran on a different JVM than the one specified in my project (I have two installed JDK on my machine), to resolve that i just modified the file *eclipse.init* in a way to ensure Eclipse will run the appropriate JVM.

This is what i added to *eclipse.init* (you need to use your exact path to `javaw.exe`):

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
```

Further informations regarding the eclipse.init file, could be found [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using maven so you need to adjust it in the compile plugin it your POM

```
   <project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

for more details check this [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i already did that, i add the code of POM in the question so you can see it