# Project 'myProject' has higher compiler option than running eclipse

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, reverse-engineering, spring-tool-suite

I am following this tutorial to use hibernate plugin in Spring tool suit [hibernate plugin][1]. I am able to install the plugin and generate hibernate configuration file. When i open the hibernate perspective i get the following error window [hibernate error][2].
i am using java 1.8. I also tried the fix suggested in this link [fix][3] but its not working.

This is how my springtoolsuit4.ini looks like after modification

```
    -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541
-product
org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM


  [1]: https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/java-hibernate-reverse-engineering-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-mysql
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIWOo.png
  [3]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27001200/project-myproject-has-higher-compiler-option-than-running-eclipse
```

Can someone please suggest what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE** : was able to fix this issue by downloading the following eclipse https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2020-06/R/eclipse-jee-2020-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip